# Error in .net: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10528769 bytes)

Tags: .net, web-services, memory, soap, size

I am trying to use a web method from one of our third party webservices into my vb.net code to retrieve information using their .net API.

When I try

```
Dim records() As WEB_API.DBRecord
records = api.GetView(guid, viewid, dbid, offset, 10000)
```

I get error from the webservice(SOAP) saying:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes 
   exhausted (tried to allocate 10528769 bytes)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage 
     message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at comp.WEB_API.XYZ.GetView(String db_guid, Int32 view_db, Int32 space_id, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Is there anything I need to fix from my end? what do you think is the cause.
let me know how I can resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: is 10000 the amount of records to retrieve?

Comment: I did give a max  limit as 10000. Whereas i have atleast 5400 records to be pulled out.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the error is happening on your third party web service. You are requesting a lot of data and they are not throttling and it is running out of memory.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. let me check with their support team.

Comment: If they are running a PHP web service ask them to set ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); - if they refuse (which is not unexpected) then tell them to throw a more meaningful error saying that you can at most ask for X records, that is, put a reasonable limit to it.

Comment: i did bring this issue to their notice. But they come up saying that this issue is unrelated to them and also suggesting to retrieve less no. of records.

Comment: Oh well. You could also trace the call with fiddler and prove to them that it is their issue - they may not be willing to admit it. They should also provide you guidance on how to retrieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your memory limit to more that 150Mb, or try to pull out less number of records every time. You are getting OOM on your side not on third-party API.

Comment: we have around 5400 records in our thirdparty database. It only allows me to retrive about 5000 records. How do i retrieve the rest? Also, help me with ways to increase the memory limit. Thanks.